# Weasyprint and CSS

Tags: python, html, css, weasyprint

I seem to be struggling with weasyprint and CSS,

The main issues that I seem to not be able to get working is background colors on things.

the HTML uses bootstrap to render and I seem to get the grid layouts and the table formatting but the background colours seem to go missing.

I have tried inline css and that does not come out either.

I know this one is a little obscure but I am not sure what to show you guys.

I am happy for feedback on the question so I can refine what I am asking.

Thanks Guys in advance

Here is the weasyprint object:

```
weasyprint.HTML(
            string=self.html_accept(request, report, clinic_id), media_type='print'
        ).write_pdf(stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(url='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css')])
```

I have also tried adding the stylesheet as a string to get the background and that does not seem to work.

Here is the HTML that I am having issues with.

```
        <tr class="table-primary text-white">
            <td></td>
            <td>&nbsp;&lt;5 years</td>
            <td>&nbsp;&ge;5yrs (excluding PW)</td>
            <td>&nbsp;Preg Women (PW)</td>
            <td>Total&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
```

and I have overridden the bootstrap colour like this.

```
        <style>
            .table-primary, .table-primary>td, .table-primary>th .table-primary>tr{
                background-color: #459EAD;
            }
        </style>
```

this works when rendering the html but not when printed to pdf

Comment: I suppose providing your code would give us more context so we could assist you further

Comment: you need to write down better code of your example. Just like this the css rules are not even working in pure html, so there you have it, if it does not even work in pure html then even less so in WeasyPrint